# Is it possible to reduce the functions for reading JSON values in this case

Tags: jquery, json

I have got a JSON format this way

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": {
            "Beverages": [
                {
                    "id": "0001",
                    "name": "Coke",
                    "image": {
                        "url": "json_images/coke.jpg",
                        "width": 200,
                        "height": 200
                    },
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category_name": "Cokecan",
                            "image": "json_images/coke_can.jpg",
                            "type": [
                                {
                                    "id": "p1",
                                    "type": "250ml",
                                    "price": "50"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "p2",
                                    "type": "300ml",
                                    "price": "60"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "0005",
                    "name": "Pepsi",
                    "image": {
                        "url": "json_images/pepsi.jpg",
                        "width": 200,
                        "height": 200
                    },
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category_name": "Pepsican",
                            "image": "json_images/pepsi_can.jpg",
                            "type": [
                                {
                                    "id": "p4",
                                    "type": "250ml",
                                    "price": "50"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My question is ,if i select Beverages from the above JSON and then Coke , i am doing the following way to get the values 250ml and 300Ml

Is there anyway that i can do it more efficient way .

**// function to return first level**

```
function returnfirstlevelValues(value) {
                  var data;
                  $.each(jsondata.items.item, function(i, v) {
                    if (i == value) {

                      data = v;
                    }
                  });
 return data;
                }
```

**// function to return second level**

```
function returnSecondlevelValues(value) {
                  var innerdata = [];
                  for (var i = 0; i < retdata.length; i++) {
                    if (retdata[i].name == value) {
                      for (var b = 0; b < retdata[i].category.length; b++) {
                        innerdata.push(retdata[i].category[b].category_name);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return innerdata;
                }
```

**// function to return third level**

```
        function returnThirdlevelValues(value) {
          var objArray = [];
          $.each(retdata, function(i, item) {

            $.each(item.category, function(j, item) {

              if (item.category_name == value) {
                obj.image = item.image;
                obj.type = [];
                obj.price = [];
    obj.id = [];
                $.each(item.type, function(k, e) {
                  obj.type.push(e.type);
                  obj.price.push(e.price);
       obj.id.push(e.id);
                });
                objArray.push(obj);
              }
            });


          });
          return objArray;


        }
```

This is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f5T9d/

Comment: you use a select box?

Comment: yes from ui , we have got the flexibility to select a value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Handling JSON**

This is how i would write it , it's old javascript & uses performant shorthands.

```
function first(value){
 return jsondata.items.item[value]||false
}

function second(value){
 var l=firstReturn.length,temp;
 while(l--){
  firstReturn[l].name!=value||(temp=firstReturn[l].category)
 };
 return temp||false
}

function third(value){
 var l=secondReturn.length,temp;
 while(l--){
  secondReturn[l]['category_name']!=value||(temp=secondReturn[l].type)
 };
 return temp||false
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/43MV2/

if the output is not what you expect just tell me and i make some modifications...

if you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , let me integrate this with my code and let you know .

Comment: Hi , I am having difficulty in integrating your code ,please see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eeL5d/1/ , the first function is returning me return type as Object Object , could you please help

Comment: the json mixes objects and arrays . in the second call an array is expected and you pass a object.. btw you are using to much code for something that should be relatively simple.Or you read about how jquery&that plugins handles json data or start with something simple. like this http://jsfiddle.net/4dvy9/ .

Comment: the last one should be secondReturn[l].type but it does not work.

Comment: Thank you let me check .

Comment: and the name to display is thirdReturn.type or secondReturn[l].type.type

Comment: Thanks for the update ,the name to display is thirdReturn.type

Answer (score 0):

you could use parseJSON from JQuery so you can treat data as objects

Comment: Even though i get that as a Object , how can that help ??